# Getting python key error in dictionary while ploting

Tags: python, dictionary, folium

I am trying to apply the if else on function which have the hex code of the color . If the value is "PU" then it should return specific color. I am applying the function on the folium map but i am having `Key Error KA`

this is the dictionary I have

```
values = {'state':['KA','BL','KPK','PU'],'Temperature':[70,56,47,30],'Lat':[24.8607,25.3960,27.7244,27.5570],'Long':[67.0011,68.3578,68.8228,68.2028]}

temp_data = pd.DataFrame(values)
state_info = temp_data.set_index('Temperature')['state'].to_dict()
print(state_info)
```

the values i am getting after `set_index()`

```
{70: 'KA', 56: 'BL', 47: 'KPK', 30: 'PU'}

dict_keys([70, 56, 47, 30])
dict_values(['KA', 'BL', 'KPK', 'PU'])
```

**I am using the dictionary to plot the different color on the specific state**

the complete code

```
def my_color_function(feature):
    """Maps low values to green and hugh values to red."""
    if state_info[feature['id']] == 'KA':
        return '#ff0000'
    else:
        return '#008000'
m = folium.Map([30.3753, 69.3451], tiles='Stamen Terrain', zoom_start=5)
state_geo = os.path.join('', 'pakistan.json')
folium.GeoJson(
    state_geo,
    style_function=lambda feature: {
        'fillColor': my_color_function(feature),
        'color' : 'black',
        'weight' : 2,
        'dashArray' : '5, 5'
        }
    ).add_to(m)

m
```

Comment: Could you provide with a `feature['id']` value as well as what's your expected output?

Comment: @Capie this the value coming from the lamdas this what i am following https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/GeoJSON_and_choropleth.ipynb#Using-choropleth-method